# Excel lookup value if found, get another value, if yes, return another value

Tags: excel, vba, function

I have a mapping table below which is used for check the value

[image]

Below picture is the result

[image]

First I need to search the key in the mapping table, if not found, input "No" in Value column, if found, check the Code column, if the value "No", return "Z1" to Value column.
I know how to use index match to return "No" value but I don't know how to check it is yes or no. Becasue if yes, I need to return another value which is "Z5".

Thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just found out the solution...

`=IFERROR(IF(INDEX(Sheet1!B:B,MATCH(Sheet2!A2,Sheet1!A:A,0))="No","Z1","Z5"),"No")`